# How to update an HTML table after new record written to sheets?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dynamic, html-table

I have a web page, which contains an html table.

With changes to a sheet (new entry), I have no luck in seeing the HTML table updating automatically, but will do so when page is refreshed.  I have tried withSuccessHandler(function) and a few other recommendations, I expect I am overlooking something simple.  Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Here are the files in the project:

[Code.gs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6iGx.png)

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate();
}

//GET DATA FROM GOOGLE SHEET AND RETURN AS AN ARRAY
function getData() {
  var spreadSheetId = "sheetID"; //CHANGE
  var dataRange = "Sheet1!A2:c11"; //CHANGE

  var range = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadSheetId, dataRange);
  var values = range.values;
  return values;
}

//INCLUDE JAVASCRIPT AND CSS FILES
//REF: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices#separate_html_css_and_javascript

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}
```

[Index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYhle.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <base target="_top">
    <!--INCLUDE REQUIRED EXTERNAL JAVASCRIPT AND CSS LIBRARIES-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
        href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
  <?!= include('JavaScript'); ?>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <br>
        <div class="row">
            <table id="data-table" class="table table-striped table-sm table-hover table-bordered">
                <!-- TABLE DATA IS ADDED BY THE showData() JAVASCRIPT FUNCTION ABOVE -->
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[JavaScript.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWaCl.png)

```
<script>
    /*
  *THIS FUNCTION CALL THE getData() FUNCTION IN THE Code.gs FILE, 
  *AND PASS RETURNED DATA TO showData() FUNCTION
  */
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showData).getData();

  //THIS FUNCTION GENERATE THE DATA TABLE FROM THE DATA ARRAY
  function showData(dataArray){
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#data-table').DataTable({
        data: dataArray,
        //TABLE HEADINGS BELOW TO MATCH WITH YOUR SELECTED DATA RANGE
        columns: [
          {"title":"First Name"},
          {"title":"Last Name"},
          {"title":"Student ID"},
        ]
      });
    });
  }
</script>
```

[HTML table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElJQx.png)